# how can I increase my swap space in this sitution?

Tags: 15.04, gparted, swap

I have 16gb Ram,but I need 48gb....so I should increase my swap space to 32.
Can I? 
I ve tried to use Gparted but it's sth such as lock (or mount)!!!!
tnx
[please see this shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3cATH.png)

Comment: @Anders It s different when my partitions are mounted

Comment: @YasharKubat OK, I see.  As for using a live distro for resizing the partitions - as suggested in the selected answer - I've had good experience with the Gparted Live CD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not manipulate (change) a partition that the system is currently using.You will have to use a live environment so as to resize your partitions.
In your case your system is using both system partition - **dev/sda4** and the swap area **dev/sda5**.

Comment: you ve right ,tnx alot